# Divisibility of a binomial coefficient by a prime

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Let $q=p^r,$ where $p\in\mathbb{P}$ is a prime and $r\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ is a natural number (non-zero). How to prove that for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,q-1\}$ the binomial coefficient $\binom{q}{i}$ is divisible by $p$?

I find it easy to show that $p|\binom{p}{i},$ but here it's more complicated :/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Since $\binom{p^r}{i}=\frac{p^r!}{i!(p^r-i)!}$, the number of $p$ dividing this number is
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{p^r}{p^n}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{i}{p^n}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{p^r-i}{p^n}\right\rfloor\right).
$$
Each term is nonnegative. Hence the sum above is at least
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{p^r}{p^r}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{i}{p^r}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{p^r-i}{p^r}\right\rfloor = 1.
$$